# I accidentally make this menu put in the backward. how to reset it?

Tags: objects

I accidentally made this menu bar disappear. I think it is put in the backward because I totally can see it through.
I don't know to reset it.

[image]

Comment: no it is not. i'm 100% sure it was just my mistake when drag and drop new window. because when i open the new file it resets to the default setting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Un-tick the box that says "Region Overlap" under `Preferences > Interface`:

[image: Box]

Comment: oh my! dude thanks! i hope you get something good deeds in return somewhere else.

Comment: Hey, no problem. I think it came checked by default when I downloaded 3.1, and it drove me nuts trying to figure it out. Glad I could help spread the solution.